# Is there a section of Stack Exchange where it is appropriate to ask this question regarding which hypothetical particles fit certain physics models?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post:  [Which hypothetical gravitons are in models where effects of mass are from specific cummulative motion patterns at small scales disturbing spacetime?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/648411/)

This is a question regarding my post which falls under the category of non-mainstream physics questions about which presumably well known hypothetical particles fit or match a given physics model or group of models matching a given description. Are there any Stack Exchange sites where this would be an appropriate question to ask? Could [Worldbuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) work?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a fit to any SE site that I know.  But since you've identified a candidate, it would be better to ask about fit to their site on their meta rather than on ours.